# Baystat240 to Nest

Tags: nest

I’m trying to install a Nest thermostat. I currently have a Baystat240 installed. I have a heat pump with electric emergency heat.

Can you tell me which wires will go where on the new nest? [![enter image description here][1]][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kvid.jpg[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you post photos of the wiring at the air-handler end please?

Comment: Posted. 

I also have a humidifier unit installed on the heat pump. Nest gave me a wiring diagram but didn’t show the brown wire that’s landed on the “T”

Comment: Can you post photos of the wiring diagram for your air-handler for that matter?